# Which directory to put snippets.json file for customization?

Tags: vim, emmet

Emmet plugin installed on my vim74.

Here are some tutorial from the mannual .
[https://docs.emmet.io/customization/snippets/](https://docs.emmet.io/customization/)

Create snippets.json file in extensions folder to add or override snippets.

```
sudo find /  -name  'snippets.jsom'
nothing as output.
```

No snippets.json in my directories,i want to create it as the mannual say,which directory to put it in?

What does extensions folder mean?
Which directory is extensions folder  for my vim and emmet?

```
tree  -L 2  /usr/share/vim
/usr/share/vim
├── addons
│   ├── doc
│   └── plugin
├── registry
│   └── vim-runtime.yaml
├── vim74
│   ├── autoload
│   ├── bugreport.vim
│   ├── bundle
│   ├── colors
│   ├── compiler
│   ├── debian.vim
│   ├── delmenu.vim
│   ├── doc
│   ├── evim.vim
│   ├── filetype.vim
│   ├── ftoff.vim
│   ├── ftplugin
│   ├── ftplugin.vim
│   ├── ftplugof.vim
│   ├── gvimrc_example.vim
│   ├── indent
│   ├── indent.vim
│   ├── indoff.vim
│   ├── keymap
│   ├── lang
│   ├── macros
│   ├── menu.vim
│   ├── mswin.vim
│   ├── optwin.vim
│   ├── plugin
│   ├── print
│   ├── rgb.txt
│   ├── scripts.vim
│   ├── spell
│   ├── synmenu.vim
│   ├── syntax
│   ├── tutor
│   └── vimrc_example.vim
├── vimfiles -> /etc/vim
├── vimrc -> /etc/vim/vimrc
└── vimrc.tiny -> /etc/vim/vimrc.tiny

tree -L 1  /usr/share/vim/vim74/autoload
/usr/share/vim/vim74/autoload
├── adacomplete.vim
├── ada.vim
├── ccomplete.vim
├── clojurecomplete.vim
├── csscomplete.vim
├── decada.vim
├── emmet
├── emmet.vim
├── getscript.vim
├── gnat.vim
├── gzip.vim
├── htmlcomplete.vim
├── javascriptcomplete.vim
├── netrwFileHandlers.vim
├── netrw_gitignore.vim
├── netrwSettings.vim
├── netrw.vim
├── paste.vim
├── phpcomplete.vim
├── python3complete.vim
├── pythoncomplete.vim
├── README.txt
├── rubycomplete.vim
├── spellfile.vim
├── sqlcomplete.vim
├── syntaxcomplete.vim
├── tar.vim
├── tohtml.vim
├── vimball.vim
├── xml
├── xmlcomplete.vim
└── zip.vim

2 directories, 30 files
tree -l 1  /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin
1 [error opening dir]
/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin
├── emmet.vim
├── getscriptPlugin.vim
├── gzip.vim
├── matchparen.vim
├── netrwPlugin.vim
├── README.txt
├── rrhelper.vim
├── spellfile.vim
├── tarPlugin.vim
├── tohtml.vim
├── vimballPlugin.vim
└── zipPlugin.vim
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.to install pathogen.vim

```
mkdir -p ~/.vim/autoload ~/.vim/bundle && \
curl -LSso ~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim https://tpo.pe/pathogen.vim
```

2.to edite snippets.json
copy  https://github.com/emmetio/emmet/blob/master/lib/snippets.json and revise something for your customization.
I want to make html:5 expand as below.

```
<html lang="zh">
<head>
    <meta charset="gbk">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>


vim  ~./vim/snippets.json
"variables": {
        "lang": "zh",
        "locale": "en-US",
        "charset": "gbk",
        "indentation": "\t",
        "newline": "\n"
    },
```

To list only part codes of it.

3.to edite your .vimrc to call snippets.json

```
vim .vimrc
let g:user_emmet_settings = webapi#json#decode(join(readfile(expand('~/.vim/snippets.json')), "\n"))
```

Answer (score 1):

The linked page says:

> Please refer to README file bundled with your editor’s plugin to find out where Emmet looks for extensions.

When you read this sentence, what is the *only* reasonable thing to do? Reading your plugin's `README`of course! A `README` that says:

> If you have installed the [web-api](https://github.com/mattn/webapi-vim) for **emmet-vim** you can also add your own snippets using a custom **snippets.json** file.
>
> Once you have installed the [web-api](https://github.com/mattn/webapi-vim) add this line to your **.vimrc**:
>
> `let g:user_emmet_settings = webapi#json#decode(join(readfile(expand('~/.snippets_custom.json')), "\n"))`
>
> You can change the **path** to your **snippets_custom.json** according to your preferences.